# How many objects can be stored in a Plone folder?

Tags: plone

For example, can I put 100.000.000 documents in one plone folder?

Comment: Do you have an actual, practical problem we can help you with? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks, I have plans to build a site to store descriptions of some objects of my country like places, schools, people, etc. That will be an open source project to publish open information. I think that dexterity could be a good tool to define diverse content types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In recent Plone releases, folders use a BTree-backed storage, so you can store as many objects in there as you like.

The biggest folder that I can access in a production environment currently stores 25k items.

You will, of course, need to deal with large numbers of items in one location appropriately. The usual caveats about really large numbers of content in a site apply.